# Explanation of Stroustrup Linearizing Class Hierarchies example

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

In Stroustrup's *C++ Programming Language* (4th ed), section 27.4.2 shows a technique to "linearize" a diamond class hierarchy to avoid the overhead of virtual base classes. He starts with the diamond pattern from a real project ([Pivot code analyzer tool](https://parasol.tamu.edu/pivot/)):

[image]

The linear version is drawn as:

[image]

and

[image]

The code outline is:

```
namespace ipr {
    struct Node { ... };
    struct Expr : Node { ... };
    struct Stmt : Expr { ... };
    struct Decl : Stmt { ... };
    struct Var : Decl { ... };

    namespace impl {
        template<class T> struct Node : T { ... };
        template<class T> struct Expr : Node<T> { ... };
        template<class S> struct Stmt : S { ... };
        template<class D> struct Decl : Stmt<Expr<D>> { ... };
        struct Var : Decl<ipr::Var> { ... };
    }
}
```

I'm confused by the irregular structure. Based on the initial description, I was expecting `impl` to look something like:

```
namespace impl {
    template<class T> struct Node : T { ... };
    template<class T> struct Expr : Node<T> { ... };
    template<class S> struct Stmt : Expr<S> { ... };
    template<class D> struct Decl : Stmt<D> { ... };
    struct Var : Decl<ipr::Var> { ... };    
}
```

And I'm thinking the full diagram of these classes is:

[image]

**My question is**, why don't the "interior" three `impl` template classes have parallel forms, as in my version of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess comes from looking at the [actual Pivot code](https://parasol.tamu.edu/pivot/doc/ipr/impl_8_h_source.html) which has

```
template<class D> struct Decl : Stmt<Node<D>> { ... };
```

instead of Stroustrup's

```
template<class D> struct Decl : Stmt<Expr<D>> { ... };
```

That suggests that `impl::Stmt` doesn't necessarily derive from `impl::Expr` after all, as in the original diamond diagram (though it still derives from the interface `ipr::Expr`). It doesn't derive from `impl::Expr` for `Decl` and `Var`, but it does for other implementation classes such as `impl::For`:

```
struct For : Stmt<Expr<ipr::For> > { ... }
```

I'm not sure why Stroustrup didn't explain the irregularity. Perhaps he thought he removed it by changing `Stmt<Node>` to `Stmt<Expr>`, or maybe he didn't change it at all (that is, the code changed after he copied it) and he wanted to leave it as is without explaining every detail.

Hopefully a better answer will explain it.